# How to have the opacity on an image move up over time, not instantly using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you hover over the each image (scroll to the right to fully see them, click on them to have them move), they move up and their brightness is decreased. When they move up, the images move over a transition of .6 seconds. I have been trying to get the darkness covering each image to move up in the same amount of time, but I can only get it to move instantly when you hover over each image. I'm new to programming and any help that I could would be good. Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks

```js
var click = 0;
function checkClicks(imgs) {

 if(click == 0) {
    // Run your animation on first click
    document.getElementById('column1').classList.add('animate1')
    document.getElementById('column2').classList.add('animate2')
    document.getElementById('column3').classList.add('animate3')
 document.getElementById('column4').classList.add('animate4')
 document.getElementById('column5').classList.add('animate5')
 document.getElementById('column6').classList.add('animate6')
 document.getElementById('column7').classList.add('animate7')
 document.getElementById('column8').classList.add('animate8')
 document.getElementById('column9').classList.add('animate9');
    // hold Images for 1s
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   myFunction(imgs);
  }, 2000);
 } else {
  myFunction(imgs);
 }

 click = 1;
}
function myFunction(imgs) {

 var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
 expandImg.src = imgs.src;
 var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
 imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("head");

 expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
   imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  background-color:#EEF0FC;
}
.column p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.column:hover p {
  opacity:1;
  top:-7px;
  transition-duration: .6s;
  height:100%;
 }

.column p {
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:black;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.column img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative; 
  top: -7px;
  transition-duration: .6s;
}

#totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 600px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  position: absolute;
  height:400px;
  left:300px;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  top: 320px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 430px;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

.head1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head5 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head7 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head8 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head9 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}


.head1::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head2::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head3::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head4::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head5::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head6::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head7::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head8::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head9::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.para1{
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 6%;
  font-size: 17px;
  top: 60px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
#column1 {
  position: absolute;
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  top:30px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate1 {
  -webkit-animation: animate1 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate1 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;

  }
}
@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;
  }
}
#column2 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:350px;
  top:50px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate2 {
  -webkit-animation: animate2 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate2 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
#column3 {
  position: absolute;
  width:260px;
  float:left;
  left:400px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate3 {
  -webkit-animation: animate3 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate3 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
#column4 {
  position: absolute;
  width:280px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate4 {
  -webkit-animation: animate4 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate4 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
#column5 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate5 {
  -webkit-animation: animate5 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate5 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
#column6 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate6 {
  -webkit-animation: animate6 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate6 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
#column7 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate7 {
  -webkit-animation: animate7 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate7 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
#column8 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate8 {
  -webkit-animation: animate8 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate8 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
#column9 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate9 {
  -webkit-animation: animate9 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate9 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
  }
}
.footer{
  position:relative;
  background-color:rgb(84,104,217);
  height:80px;
  top:546px;
  color:white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.footwords{
  padding-top:32px;
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  position: relative;
  left:6%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) and (min-width: 1150px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:350px;
    left:262px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1150px) and (min-width: 1050px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: navy;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:340px;
    left:252px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) and (min-width: 930px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: brown;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:300px;
    left:228px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 930px) and (min-width: 850px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: magenta;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:270px;
    left:210px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) and (min-width: 800px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:250px;
    left:188px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 735px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:230px;
    left:178px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 735px) and (min-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: moccasin;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:210px;
    left:150px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/fix.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body id='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id='column1'>
      <img class='arcadeimg' src="../Images/arcade.jpeg" alt="Arcade" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head1'> Parapraph #1 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>"  onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p id='column1p'>this will be shown on the hover 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column2'>
      <img src="../Images/car.png"
        alt="Car" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>this will be shown on the hover 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column3'>
      <img src="../Images/pinball.jpeg" alt="Pinball Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column4'>
      <img src="../Images/vending.jpeg" alt="Vending Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column5'>
      <img src="../Images/sriraques.jpeg" alt="Sriracha Quesadillas" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head5'> Parapraph #5 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column6'>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTWUVh_Aa4CeLecqvG5L-Xzej1kc1tKwDriiWAVWuUMms5JLHQt&usqp=CAU" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head6'>  web code </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column7'>
      <img src="https://opticsmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/a-telescope.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head7'> computer </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column8'>
      <img src="https://nctennis.com/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=13&image_path=/images/2018/11/27/Wheelchair.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head8'> adap tennis </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column9'>
      <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/77/170477-050-1C747EE3/Laptop-computer.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head9'> telescope </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 9</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class='footer'>
    <p class='footwords'>
      © 2020 By Rom Fradkin. Proudly Individually Coded.
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your problem is the white space showing below image while hovering?

Comment: yes because the shadow covering the image moves instantly, while the image takes .6 seconds to move up. I want the darkness covering the image to also move up over a .6 second period so they are in line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is apply same time duration on both the elements, and change the position on hover of column as you were doing with Paragraph.

and it will be better if you will transform the whole column not the separate inner items, Because Transition property you should use very carefully as it will effect the GPU performance and sometime you will see a lag or jerk in transtions,

```js
var click = 0;
function checkClicks(imgs) {

 if(click == 0) {
    // Run your animation on first click
    document.getElementById('column1').classList.add('animate1')
    document.getElementById('column2').classList.add('animate2')
    document.getElementById('column3').classList.add('animate3')
 document.getElementById('column4').classList.add('animate4')
 document.getElementById('column5').classList.add('animate5')
 document.getElementById('column6').classList.add('animate6')
 document.getElementById('column7').classList.add('animate7')
 document.getElementById('column8').classList.add('animate8')
 document.getElementById('column9').classList.add('animate9');
    // hold Images for 1s
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   myFunction(imgs);
  }, 2000);
 } else {
  myFunction(imgs);
 }

 click = 1;
}
function myFunction(imgs) {

 var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
 expandImg.src = imgs.src;
 var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
 imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("head");

 expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
   imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  background-color:#EEF0FC;
}
.column p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.column p {
  transition: top .6s;
  transition-duration: .6s;
 top: 0;
}
.column:hover p {
  opacity:1;
  top:-7px;
  height:100%;
 }

.column p {
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:black;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.column:hover img {
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative; 
  top: -7px;
  transition-duration: .6s;
}

#totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 600px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  position: absolute;
  height:400px;
  left:300px;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  top: 320px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 430px;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

.head1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head5 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head7 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head8 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head9 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}


.head1::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head2::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head3::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head4::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head5::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head6::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head7::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head8::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head9::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.para1{
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 6%;
  font-size: 17px;
  top: 60px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
#column1 {
  position: absolute;
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  top:30px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate1 {
  -webkit-animation: animate1 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate1 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;

  }
}
@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;
  }
}
#column2 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:350px;
  top:50px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate2 {
  -webkit-animation: animate2 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate2 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
#column3 {
  position: absolute;
  width:260px;
  float:left;
  left:400px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate3 {
  -webkit-animation: animate3 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate3 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
#column4 {
  position: absolute;
  width:280px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate4 {
  -webkit-animation: animate4 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate4 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
#column5 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate5 {
  -webkit-animation: animate5 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate5 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
#column6 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate6 {
  -webkit-animation: animate6 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate6 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
#column7 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate7 {
  -webkit-animation: animate7 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate7 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
#column8 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate8 {
  -webkit-animation: animate8 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate8 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
#column9 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate9 {
  -webkit-animation: animate9 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate9 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
  }
}
.footer{
  position:relative;
  background-color:rgb(84,104,217);
  height:80px;
  top:546px;
  color:white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.footwords{
  padding-top:32px;
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  position: relative;
  left:6%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) and (min-width: 1150px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:350px;
    left:262px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1150px) and (min-width: 1050px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: navy;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:340px;
    left:252px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) and (min-width: 930px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: brown;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:300px;
    left:228px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 930px) and (min-width: 850px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: magenta;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:270px;
    left:210px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) and (min-width: 800px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:250px;
    left:188px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 735px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:230px;
    left:178px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 735px) and (min-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: moccasin;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:210px;
    left:150px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/fix.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body id='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id='column1'>
      <img class='arcadeimg' src="../Images/arcade.jpeg" alt="Arcade" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head1'> Parapraph #1 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>"  onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p id='column1p'>this will be shown on the hover 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column2'>
      <img src="../Images/car.png"
        alt="Car" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>this will be shown on the hover 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column3'>
      <img src="../Images/pinball.jpeg" alt="Pinball Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column4'>
      <img src="../Images/vending.jpeg" alt="Vending Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column5'>
      <img src="../Images/sriraques.jpeg" alt="Sriracha Quesadillas" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head5'> Parapraph #5 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column6'>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTWUVh_Aa4CeLecqvG5L-Xzej1kc1tKwDriiWAVWuUMms5JLHQt&usqp=CAU" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head6'>  web code </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column7'>
      <img src="https://opticsmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/a-telescope.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head7'> computer </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column8'>
      <img src="https://nctennis.com/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=13&image_path=/images/2018/11/27/Wheelchair.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head8'> adap tennis </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column9'>
      <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/77/170477-050-1C747EE3/Laptop-computer.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head9'> telescope </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 9</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class='footer'>
    <p class='footwords'>
      © 2020 By Rom Fradkin. Proudly Individually Coded.
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```